# Installation error while installing npm package of indy-sdk on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

Actually I was installing `aries js framework` But the issue specifically comes when it install one of its dependency `indy-SDK` npm package. I am quite new with the Hyperledger and i am not sure what's causing the issue.

I don't understand whether the exact issue is with **node gyp** or **windows SDK build tool** or **visual studio tools**.

Anybody who has worked with Hyperledger can easily understand what's the issue. Please let me know if you know something that can resolve the issue.

I have already installed docker and indy SDK image on it. And can successfully run indy pool of nodes. But i need to interact with them using java-script. And this issue is the problem that has been a hurdle for me since past day.

```js
D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project>npm i @aries-framework/node
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated @unimodules/core@7.1.2: replaced by the 'expo' package, learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/whats-new-in-expo-modules-infrastructure-7a7cdda81ebc
npm WARN deprecated @unimodules/react-native-adapter@6.3.9: replaced by the 'expo' package, learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/whats-new-in-expo-modules-infrastructure-7a7cdda81ebc

//---Here the issue starts---
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules\indy-sdk
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.7 found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.4.33213.308) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Practice Code\\Blockchain Projects\\Hyperledger Project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules\indy-sdk
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-25T13_39_10_348Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Error message says there is failure while running the `node-gyp rebuild` command on the `indy-sdk module` in the `D:\Practice Code\Blockchain Projects\Hyperledger Project\node_modules` directory.
2. Another issue is that build process could not find a suitable installation of `Visual Studio` to use, which is required to build native `Node.js modules` on Windows.
3. What is more you need to install the latest version of `Visual Studio`, including the `Desktop development with C++` workload, and also make sure that it is properly configured. After all changes try again with `npm install.`